# How to set specific startup routines?

Tags: macos, startup

Another simple question for those keeping track, but I was wondering how and where I could setup the startup routines for my mac. What I would really like is for email to open, messages and activity monitor to open but not in a new window, and for safari to open in fullscreen mode in a separate pane. Is this possible or at least where might I look? I'm less interested in accomplishing this as learning some of the more behind the scenes stuff related to the operating system.

Comment: Depends on how complex you want it go, simple things such as opening App can done as @bmike mentioned from Start Up Items. If you want more complex things like opening Safari in full screen, or running some script can be accomplished with Launch Agents.

Answer (score 2):

Open system references and go to the accounts or users section.

Add the applications needing to start to each user's startup items. You can start apps (and optionally hide them) and mount shares as well as start automation scripts.